# How to get a controller offset from a class by calling it from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 classes here,

The First class :

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Another Screen'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon:  Icon(Icons.now_widgets_rounded),
              label: 'Login Screen'),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
```

And the Other Class:

```
class AnotherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const AnotherScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<AnotherScreen> createState() => AnotherScreenState();
}

class AnotherScreenState extends State<AnotherScreen> {
ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

List<Color> colors = [
Colors.black12,
Colors.red,
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 2,
    controller: controller,
    itemBuilder: (___, index) => Container(
      color: colors[index],
      child: Text(
        index.toString(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

What I want that when I changed the index of the tabs in the first class, I want inside the onTap method in the First Class to get the controller of the Another class before I changed the current index to a new index.

Comment: Using [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) you can create the `ScrollController` in a `ChangeNotifierProvider` placed above both widgets in the widget tree. After this you can use `context.read` to get this provider and access the `ScrollController`. But other state management solutions can work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Riverpod provider for the ScrollController in your AnotherScreenState class:

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final scrollControllerProvider = Provider<ScrollController>((ref) {
  return ScrollController();
});
```

In your AnotherScreenState class, use the scrollControllerProvider:

```
class AnotherScreenState extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnotherScreenStateState createState() => _AnotherScreenStateState();
}

class _AnotherScreenStateState extends ConsumerState<AnotherScreenState> {
  List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.black12,
    Colors.red,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final scrollController = ref.read(scrollControllerProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 2,
        controller: scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (___, index) => Container(
          color: colors[index],
          child: Text(
            index.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Modify your BottomNavigationBar to use Riverpod:

```
Consumer(
  builder: (_, ref, __) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'Another Screen'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon:  Icon(Icons.now_widgets_rounded),
                  label: 'Login Screen'),
            ],
            onTap: (index) {
              final scrollController = ref.read(scrollControllerProvider); // You can use the controller now

              setState(() {
                currentIndex = index;
              });
            },
          );
  }
),
```

Feel free to adapt the solution to your chosen state management approach. The key concept remains the same: accessing the ScrollController before changing the tab index to perform any necessary operations.